# Como inverter uma string em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string

Como inverter uma string em JavaScript? Por exemplo:

Entrada:

> "alguma coisa aqui"

Saída:

> "iuqa asioc amugla"

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Faça assim:

```
'texto aqui'.split('').reverse().join(''); // 'iuqa otxet'
```

Mais exemplos:

```
'♕ ♖ ♗ ♘'.split('').reverse().join(''); // '♘ ♗ ♖ ♕'

'サブリミナルメッセージ'.split('').reverse().join(''); // 'ジーセッメルナミリブサ'

'✓ ✔ ✕ ✖ ✗ ✘ ✙ ✚ ✛ ✜ ✝ ✞'.split('').reverse().join(''); // ✞ ✝ ✜ ✛ ✚ ✙ ✘ ✗ ✖ ✕ ✔ ✓

'ＳＴＡＣＫＯＶＥＲＦＬＯＷ'.split('').reverse().join(''); // ＷＯＬＦＲＥＶＯＫＣＡＴＳ

'▁▂▃▄▆▇█'.split('').reverse().join(''); // █▇▆▄▃▂▁

'ab'.split('').reverse().join(''); // ba
```

Comment: +1. Pessoalmente nem sei se existe um meio _melhor_ ou mais rápido do que esse

Comment: Não funciona...

Comment: Claro que funciona.

Comment: ah sim, é verdade

Comment: Está errada para caracteres que ocupem mais de uma code unit. Esperimentem `Olá &#x01D49E;!`

Comment: @luiscubal Uma resposta que atenda a esse requisito (tratar corretamente de *surrogate pairs* e caracteres combinantes) de fato seria bastante interessante!

Comment: @mgibsonbr Estou a trabalhar numa. Já tenho não-BMPs a funcionar, mas faltam-me combinantes.

Comment: Quase 'pythônico' :)

Comment: Não consigo fazer upload da minha resposta. Até conseguir, fica o jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/E6yb8/1/

Comment: Pronto. Consegui finalmente fazer o upload. Nota: O stackoverflow não lida bem com caracteres unicode inválidos.

Comment: Belos exemplos, vejo uma ótima funcionalidade. - Obs: Nunca tinha notado que `STACKOVERFLOW` ao contrário ficava `ＷＯＬＦＲＥＶＯＫＣＡＴＳ` isso me lembrou thundercats de alguma forma.

Comment: A tradução desse texto chinês mostra que é um pouco ofensivo, não?

Comment: @acelent Ainda bem que estamos no SO-PT, e não no Mandarim. =)

Answer (score 64):

Tanto a resposta do Gabriel Santos como a do mgibsonbr estão erradas (embora funcionem bem nalguns casos limitados que acabam por ser os mais comuns).

**Porque motivo estão erradas?**

Unicode. Nos tempos ancestrais (ASCII), cada caracter ocupava um espaço constante, mas isso já não é verdade.

O JavaScript usa o sistema UTF-16, em que aquilo a que a maioria das pessoas associa a caracter (um *grafema*) é dividido em "code points", que por sua vez são divididos em "code units".

Um caracter pode ter um ou mais code point e cada code point pode ter um ou dois code units. O primeiro é o code point "principal" e os seguintes (opcionais) são modificadores que acrescentam algo ao caracter (exemplo: acentos).
Quando um code point ocupa dois code units em UTF-16, diz-se que o primeiro é o "High Surrogate" (ou lead surrogate) e o segundo é o "Low Surrogate" (ou trail surrogate). Quando um code point ocupa um só code unit diz-se que está no Basic Multilingual Plane (BMP).

Exemplo de um caracter que falha nas respostas apresentas: o caracter ͆.
O caracter que eu coloquei é constituido por dois code points: O caracter  e o modificador ͆ .
O code point , por sua vez, ocupa dois code units.

Se calcular o inverso de "Olá  ͆!" com as outras funções vai obter !͆ �� ́alO, que é claramente o resultado errado.

**A solução**

A solução completa ([jsfiddle de teste](http://jsfiddle.net/E6yb8/12/)) é a seguinte:

```
// Procurei na norma do Unicode e não encontrei informação
// suficiente sobre como lidar com strings que comecem em
// combining code points.
var ReversalMode = {
    //Assume uma string "normal"
    'PERMISSIVE': 0,
    // Substitui um caracter pelo <?> (U+FFFD REPLACEMENT CHARACTER)
    // quando não o reconhece.
    'STRICT': 1,
    // Por defeito, usar o modo STRICT.
    'DEFAULT': 1,
    // Semelhante a STRICT, mas pode acrescentar code points ao inicio
    // de uma string se esta começar por um combining.
    'COMPLETE_COMBINING': 3,
    // Semelhante a COMPLETE_COMBINING, mas sem substituir caracteres
    // inválidos pelo <?>
    'PERMISSIVE_COMPLETE_COMBINING': 2
};

String.prototype.isHighSurrogate = function () {
    var charCode = this.charCodeAt(0);
    return charCode >= 0xD800 && charCode <= 0xDBFF;
}

String.prototype.isLowSurrogate = function () {
    var charCode = this.charCodeAt(0);
    return charCode >= 0xDC00 && charCode <= 0xDFFF;
};

String.prototype.isCombining = function () {    

    if (this.length != 1) {
        //Todos os caracteres de combinação estão no BMP
        return false;
    }

    var codePoint = this.charCodeAt(0);

    //Combining Diacritical Marks
    if (codePoint >= 0x0300 && codePoint <= 0x036F)
        return true;
    //Combining Diacritical Marks Supplement
    if (codePoint >= 0x1DC0 && codePoint <= 0x1DFF)
        return true;
    //Combining Diacritical Marks for Symbols
    if (codePoint >= 0x20D0 && codePoint <= 0x20FF)
        return true;
    //Combining Half Marks
    if (codePoint >= 0xFE20 && codePoint <= 0xFE2F)
        return true;

    return false;
}

String.prototype.codePoints = function (strictMode) {

    var codePoints = [];

    var currentPoint = '';

    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; ++i) {
        var currentUnit = this[i];

        if (currentUnit.isHighSurrogate()) {
            if (currentPoint.length !== 0 && strictMode) {
                codePoints.push('\uFFFD');
                currentPoint = '';
            }
            else {
                currentPoint += currentUnit;
            }
        } else {
            if (currentUnit.isLowSurrogate() && strictMode &&
               currentPoint.length !== 1) {

                codePoints.push('\uFFFD');
                currentPoint = '';
            } else {
                currentPoint += currentUnit;

                codePoints.push(currentPoint);
                currentPoint = '';
            }
        }
    }

    if (currentPoint !== '') {
        if (strictMode) {
            codePoints.push('\uFFFD');
        }
        else {
            codePoints.push(currentPoint);
        }
    }

    return codePoints;
}

String.prototype.chars = function (strictMode) {
    var chars = [];

    var codePoints = this.codePoints(strictMode);
    var currentChar = '';

    for (var i = 0; i < codePoints.length; ++i) {
        var codePoint = codePoints[i];

        if (!codePoint.isCombining() && currentChar != '') {
            chars.push(currentChar);
            currentChar = '';
        }

        currentChar += codePoint;
    }

    if (currentChar !== '') {
        // Tecnicamente, esta verificação não é necessária para o
        // reverse, porque o join('') trata disso, mas para outros
        // usos de chars() isto evita que nalguns casos fique uma
        // string vazia no final do array (quando o último elemento
        // não é um combinador)
        chars.push(currentChar);
    }

    return chars;
}

String.prototype.reverse = function (reversalMode) {
    if (reversalMode === undefined) {
        reversalMode = ReversalMode.DEFAULT;
    }
    var chars = this.chars(reversalMode & ReversalMode.STRICT);
    if (chars.length > 0 && chars[0].isCombining()) {
        switch (reversalMode) {
            case ReversalMode.COMPLETE_COMBINING:
            case ReversalMode.PERMISSIVE_COMPLETE_COMBINING:
                chars[0] = '\u00A0' + chars[0];
                break;
            case ReversalMode.STRICT:
                chars[0] = '\uFFFD';
                break;
        }
    }
    return chars.reverse().join('');
}
```

Para usar o código acima, use `"String a inverter".reverse()`.

Comment: Bela resposta! Me ajudou a entender melhor o UTF-16.

Comment: Resposta extraordinária. Muito boa a sua explicação, eu não sabia de nada disso que você disse, somou muito pra mim!

Comment: "Tanto a resposta do Gabriel Santos como a do mgibsonbr estão erradas" **erradas**? Você diria que as leis de Newton estão "erradas" (diante da relatividade de Einstein)? Eu diria **"limitadas"** - no sentido que são respostas corretas se o domínio forem strings no BMP utilizando somente caracteres pré-compostos. Em todo caso, sua resposta é de fato mais completa, +1 e vou incluir um link pra sua resposta a partir da minha.

Comment: @mgibsonbr Uma coisa ou está errada ou está certa. As outras respostas estão certas nalguns casos, e erradas noutros. Se eu responder que "x + 1 = 2", eu vou estar errado sempre que x != 1. De fato, eu diria que as leis de Newton estão erradas. São úteis e funcionam nalguns casos, mas estão erradas. Peço desculpa se ofendi alguém, mas pareceu-me uma forma direta e eficaz de transmitir a minha mensagem (que é: não ignorar o Unicode).

Comment: @luiscubal Não ofendeu, afinal numa ciência exata não existe meio-termo. Entretanto, algo que é verdadeiro num domínio pode não ser necessariamente verdadeiro num domínio mais amplo (ex.: não existe raiz de `-1` se o domínio forem os Números Reais).

Comment: @mgibsonbr Certo. Há cenários em que as outras respostas funcionam perfeitamente (exemplo: interação com um sistema antigo que nunca será atualizado e só suporta a língua inglesa). Nesses casos usar a minha resposta é desnecessário ao ponto de ser ridículo.

Comment: Só por curiosidade, essa resposta suporta UTF-32? Se não, já que se prestou a escrever uma que suporte UTF-16, poderia pelo menos explicitar que ela não serve para o 32. Na real eu não sei bem se os asiáticos usam UTF-32.

Comment: @EmersonRochaLuiz O JavaScript não usa UTF-32. Se usasse, a função `codePoints` ficava mais simples (aí é que era só um `split('')`), a `isHighSurrogate` desaparecia, a `isCombining` perdia a verificação do length, e o resto ficava igual. Em UTF-32 code point = code unit.

Comment: Resposta muito massa. Mas, é só pra mim que os caracteres unicode no post dessa resposta (por exemplo, esse: ͆) não são corretamente exibidos no Chrome? (no Firefox e no IE eles aparecem corretamente...)

Comment: @LuizVieira Nem todos os tipos de letra(fonts) suportam todas as letras. E quanto menos comum a letra, menos probabilidade há de ter suporte. Letras fora do BMP são muito incomuns.

Comment: Esta resposta é a correcta. Por razões históricas, [os nomes de ficheiros em HFS+](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/technotes/tn/tn1150.html#HFSPlusNames) são [normalizados](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/technotes/tn/tn1150.html#UnicodeSubtleties) com uma espécie de [NFD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_normalization#Normalization), em vez de NFC como o resto do mundo. Se, em OS X, se passar um nome de ficheiro a um script, `node hello-world.js "Olá.txt"`, este "Olá.txt" tem um "a" seguido de um acento agudo compositor (U+0302) (o Terminal atrofia-se com isto).

Comment: @LeandroAmorim Não tenho a certeza que tenha resposta certa, visto que os caracteres combinantes aparecem *depois* do caracter que alteram. Experimentei isso mas o Firefox e o C#+WPF dão resultados diferentes. Mas, fora isso, creio que a melhor aproximação seria `a &#x301;a &#x301;a`. Os acentos são aplicados ao espaço, não ao `a`, pelo que pô-los no `a` na versão invertida seria incorreto.

Comment: A junção de um diacrítico+letra `&#x0301;a` gera o feito para o visualizador diferente da letra+diacrítico `a&#x0301;` que nesse segundo caso a letra apareceria acentuada. Então como deve se comportar o script que inverte as letras? ele deve inserir um espaço entre a letra e o diacrítico `a &#x0301;` para que o acento continue fora da letra ou deve-se aceitar que a letra antes não acentuada apresente o acento?

Comment: @luiscubal acabei excluindo o comentário anterior pra torná-lo mais claro.

Comment: Então o ideal para transformar o `&#x0301;a &#x0301;a &#x0301;a` em `a &#x0301; a &#x0301; a &#x0301;`? ou transformar em `a &#x0301;a &#x0301;a &#x0301;`?

Comment: @LeandroAmorim Mas nem sempre tenho esse comportamento. Em Firefox, ele parece ignorar o primeiro acento (embora tenha um comportamento inconsistente -- às vezes ele cria um espaço com acento). Em WPF, ele faz com que o primeiro `a` tenha dois acentos (mas com um aspeto bem diferente do a&#x0301;&#x0301;)

Comment: hmmm... "In the Unicode Standard, all sequences of character codes are permitted. This does not create an obligation on implementations to support all possible combinations equally well. " (pag. 42, Unicode Standard 6.2) Tradução "Em Unicode, todos as sequências de code points são permitidas. No entanto, as implementações não são obrigadas a suportar todas as combinações possíveis igualmente bem"

Comment: Mas, logo na página seguinte: "all combining characters are  o be used in sequence following the base characters to which they apply." Tradução: "todos os caracteres combinantes são para ser usados em sequência depois dos caracteres base aos quais são aplicados." Outra seção menciona o code point A0, que pode ser usado para quando se quer caracteres combinantes isolados.

Comment: @LeandroAmorim, note que o inverso de `"\u0301a"` tanto pode ser `"a \u0301"` na tentativa de preservar o acento, como pode ser `"a"` por descartar carácteres combinatórios que não se aplicam a nada. Agora penso que `"a \u0301"` deve, sem dúvida nenhuma, tornar-se `" \u0301a"`.

Comment: Eu pessoalmente assumiria "garbage in, garbage out" (lixo entra, lixo sai). Ou seja, se há um caractere combinante no início da string - portanto combinando nada - ter esse caractere no final da string mesmo que isso afete uma letra qualquer (i.e. mude os grafemas) é "bom o bastante". Não me parece existir comportamento correto nesse caso, então ficaria com um que alterasse a string o mínimo possível (i.e. sou contra introduzir um code point novo - `" "` - ou remover um code point existente).

Comment: @LeandroAmorim @mgibsonbr  Novo jsfiddle, espero que sirva. O "garbage-in garbage-out" que não acrescenta nada é o modo `PERMISSIVE`, o "completar" caracter é o `COMPLETE_COMBINING`. O substituir tudo o que é inválido por � é o `STRICT`.

Comment: Só pra constar, o Unicode tem muito mais bizarrices do que a gente pode conceber, e sempre tem alguma coisa faltando. Por exemplo, alguns grapheme clusters não são tratados corretamente, como os emojis de bandeira: https://ideone.com/dUsdi2 - De qualquer forma não invalida a resposta, que aliás é muito boa (já tinha dado +1 antes, mas só hoje resolvi testar para esses casos)

Answer (score 30):

Existem várias formas de implementação da função reverse sendo que algumas possuem maior performance de acordo com o browser.

**1. Loop decremental com concatenação**

```
function reverse(s) {
    var o = '';
    for (var i = s.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        o += s[i];
    }
    return o;
}
```

**2. Loop Incremental/Decremental com dois arrays**

```
function reverse(s) {
    var o = [];
    for (var i = s.length - 1, j = 0; i >= 0; i--, j++) {
        o[j] = s[i];
    }
    return o.join('');
}
```

**3. Loop Incremental com array pushing e charAt**

```
function reverse(s) {
    var o = [];
    for (var i = 0, len = s.length; i <= len; i++)
        o.push(s.charAt(len - i));
    return o.join('');
}
```

**4. Funcões nativas**

```
function reverse(s) {
    return s.split('').reverse().join('');
}
```

**5. Loop com `while` com concatenação e `substring`**

```
function reverse(s) {
    var i = s.length,
        o = '';
    while (i > 0) {
        o += s.substring(i - 1, i);
        i--;
    }
    return o;
}
```

**6. Declaração simples de Loop usando `for` com concatenação**

```
function reverse(s) {
    for (var i = s.length - 1, o = ''; i >= 0; o += s[i--]) { }
    return o;
}
```

**7. Recursividade com `substring` e `charAt`**

```
function reverse(s) {
    return (s === '') ? '' : reverse(s.substr(1)) + s.charAt(0);
}
```

**8. Recursão com função interna**

```
function reverse(s) {
    function rev(s, len, o) {
        return (len === 0) ? o : rev(s, --len, (o += s[len]));
    };
    return rev(s, s.length, '');
}
```

**9. Troca de índice intermediario usando `for`**

```
function reverse(s) {
    s = s.split('');
    var len = s.length,
        halfIndex = Math.floor(len / 2) - 1,
        tmp;
    for (var i = 0; i <= halfIndex; i++) {
        tmp = s[len - i - 1];
        s[len - i - 1] = s[i];
        s[i] = tmp;
    }
    return s.join('');
}
```

**10. Troca de índice intermediario usando recursividade**

```
function reverse(s) {
    if (s.length < 2) {
        return s;
    }
    var halfIndex = Math.ceil(s.length / 2);
    return reverse(s.substr(halfIndex)) +
           reverse(s.substr(0, halfIndex));
}
```

**Performance**

Usando a ferramenta [JSPerf](http://jsperf.com/), foi comparado a performance de cada função. 
Chegando no seguinte resultado

[image: Gráfico mostrando a performance das implementações em quatro browsers]

Chrome 15 - Implementação 1 e 6
Firefox 7 - Implementação 6
IE 9 - Implementação 4
Opera 12 - Implementação 9

**Conclusão**

Aparentemente a melhor implementação é a primeira, pois apresentou resultados aceitáveis em todos os browsers. A nona implementação apresenta bons resultados e é indicada pra strings muito longas.

[Fonte](http://eddmann.com/posts/ten-ways-to-reverse-a-string-in-javascript/)

Comment: Bela resposta!!

Comment: Boa resposta mesmo! Sobre o gráfico, mesmo que as barras estejam apresentadas da esquerda para a direita com os valores das opções de 1 a 10, talvez fosse intessante colocar uma legenda com as cores para tornar mais clara a informação e mais fácil a comparação. :)

Answer (score 15):

> Nota: essa resposta assume strings no [BMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_%28Unicode%29#Basic_Multilingual_Plane) sem caracteres combinantes ([apenas pré-compostos](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode#Caracteres_pr.C3.A9-compostos_e_caracteres_combinados)) - o que em muitas aplicações práticas é bom o suficiente. Para uma solução mais completa, ver [a resposta do @luiscubal](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/5952/215).

Se a performance não for crucial, a solução mais simples seria [a resposta do @Gabriel Santos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/5944/215). Caso contrário, vendo [esse teste no jsperf](http://jsperf.com/string-reverse/4), eu diria que o meio mais eficiente é:

```
function str_reverse2(str) {
    var result = '',
        length = str.length;
    while (length--) {
        result += str[length];
    }
    return result;
}
```

P.S. Contra-intuitivamente, eu tenho observado que operações simples de concatenação de strings têm performance melhor na prática do que a técnica recomendada de acumular strings menores num array e depois fazer `join`. Observei isso em outras situações também.

Comment: +1 porque as opções sem uso de `split/reverse/join` são mais mesmo rápidas. Mas eu ainda usaria o outro modo em algo que não fosse _realmente_ necessário performance, como um loop

Comment: @EmersonRochaLuiz Concordo! Se o gargalo da aplicação não estiver ali, pra que complicar? 90% das vezes a solução mais simples/legível/concisa será a melhor.

Answer (score 11):

Enquanto sei que essa pergunta tem boas respostas, tanto para o caso habitual quanto para casos mais exóticos envolvendo *surrogate pairs*. Acho justo mencionar que existem bibliotecas para resolver esse problema.

O [Mathias Bynens](http://mathiasbynens.be/), autor mencionado [na resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/6784/100) do João Paraná, responsável, entre outros, pelo [jsPerf.com](http://jsperf.com/) e [HTML5 Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/) criou uma biblioteca chamada **[esrever](http://git.io/esrever)** com o único propósito de inverter Strings.

## Exemplo de uso

```
var input = 'alguma coisa aqui';
var reversed = esrever.reverse(input);
console.log(reversed);
// → 'iuqa asioc amugla'
esrever.reverse(reversed) == input;
// → true
```

A biblioteca funciona com strings exóticas e possui um grande número de testes unitários (inclusive passou do teste do [Zalgo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/664577)):

[ZA̡͊͠͝LGΌ ISͮ̂҉̯͈͕̹̘̱ TO͇̹̺ͅƝ̴ȳ̳ TH̘Ë͖́̉ ͠P̯͍̭O̚​N̐Y̡ H̸̡̪̯ͨ͊̽̅̾̎Ȩ̬̩̾͛ͪ̈́̀́͘ ̶̧̨̱̹̭̯ͧ̾ͬC̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍M̲̖͊̒ͪͩͬ̚̚͜Ȇ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝S̨̥̫͎̭ͯ̿̔̀ͅ - Demo](http://mothereff.in/reverse-string#ZA%CD%A0%CC%A1%CD%8A%CD%9DLG%CE%8C%20IS%CD%AE%CC%82%D2%89%CC%AF%CD%88%CD%95%CC%B9%CC%98%CC%B1%20TO%CD%85%CD%87%CC%B9%CC%BA%C6%9D%CC%B4%C8%B3%CC%B3%20TH%CC%98E%CD%84%CC%89%CD%96%20%CD%A0P%CC%AF%CD%8D%CC%ADO%CC%9A%E2%80%8BN%CC%90Y%CC%A1%20H%CD%A8%CD%8A%CC%BD%CC%85%CC%BE%CC%8E%CC%A1%CC%B8%CC%AA%CC%AFE%CC%BE%CD%9B%CD%AA%CD%84%CC%80%CC%81%CC%A7%CD%98%CC%AC%CC%A9%20%CD%A7%CC%BE%CD%AC%CC%A7%CC%B6%CC%A8%CC%B1%CC%B9%CC%AD%CC%AFC%CD%AD%CC%8F%CD%A5%CD%AE%CD%9F%CC%B7%CC%99%CC%B2%CC%9D%CD%96O%CD%AE%CD%8F%CC%AE%CC%AA%CC%9D%CD%8DM%CD%8A%CC%92%CC%9A%CD%AA%CD%A9%CD%AC%CC%9A%CD%9C%CC%B2%CC%96E%CC%91%CD%A9%CD%8C%CD%9D%CC%B4%CC%9F%CC%9F%CD%99%CC%9ES%CD%AF%CC%BF%CC%94%CC%A8%CD%80%CC%A5%CD%85%CC%AB%CD%8E%CC%AD)

---

**[Demo online](http://mothereff.in/reverse-string)** utilizando a ferramenta.

É sempre bacana usar e contribuir com um bom projeto open source ao invés de reinventar a roda.

Comment: @luiscubal, a sua ideia de incluir "modos" para reverter a String é muito interessante, quem sabe um *pull request* para a biblioteca.

Answer (score 5):

Uma função para fazer o reverso do texto inclusive para UTF-16 [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vbcVa/1/)

```
function Reverso(input) {
    var s = input, c = 1, r = '', l = '', h = /[\uD800-\uDFFF]/;
    var b = /([\u0300-\u036F|\u1DC0-\u1DFF|\u20D0-\u20FF|\uFE20-\uFE2F])/;
    while(s.length){
        l = s.substr(0,1);
        if(h.test(l)) c++;
        while(b.test(s.substr(c,1))&&l!=' ') c++;
        r = (b.test(l)?' ':'') + s.substr(0,c) + r;
        s = s.substr(c);
        c = 1;
    }
    return r;
}
```

Aparentemente temos um problema quando `^a` é invertido. A resposta correta seria `a^` porém o html ao combinar `a+^` gera `â` dessa maneira o script anterior inclui um espaço para que a saída seja `a^`.

Comment: Não funciona para caracteres *dentro* do BMP com combinatórios depois (devido ao `cc>=2`) Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/v98AY/

Comment: Você tinha razão, obrigado.

Comment: A nova versão parece funcionar bem, pelo menos nos casos que eu testei.

Comment: usei `teste de inversão da frase` e o resultado foi `frase da inversão deteste` comendo o ultimo espaço

Comment: @Spark Confirmo: http://jsfiddle.net/EC4Qd/1/

Answer (score 5):

Minha solução usa https://raw2.github.com/bestiejs/punycode.js/master/punycode.js e foi baseada [neste artigo](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-encoding) excelente (em ingles) do *Mathias Bynens*

A solução funciona para qualquer string UTF-16 incluindo aquelas compostas por um ou mais  **surrogate pair**

Veja meu código abaixo:

**HTML**

```
<script src="/js/api/punycode.js"></script>

<div id="utf16" style="color: green;"></div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script>
    (function() {
        var reverse = function(str) {
            var myStrArray = punycode.ucs2.decode(str)
            var result = [], length = myStrArray.length;
            var i = 0;
            while (length--) {
                result[i++] = myStrArray[length];
            }
            return punycode.ucs2.encode(result);
        }
        var str = 'Olá  ! Cuidado pois tem também esse caracter  que é um surrogate pair.';
        var div = document.getElementById('utf16');
        div.innerHTML = str + ' E SEU REVERSO É : '+ reverse(str);
    })();
</script>
```

Comment: Interessante o uso de [Punycode](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode)! E esse artigo me fez lembrar de algo que já suspeitava, mas achava que havia sido "superado": o fato de JavaScript **não obrigar** o uso de UTF-16. P.S. Pena que seu `reverse` não funciona com caracteres combinantes... (experimente `var str = 'Ola\u0301';`)

Comment: realmente @mgibsonbr, eu tinha verificado isso mas resolvi postar assim mesmo para manter a solução simples. Quando tiver um tempo aqui posso melhorá-lo para tratar este caso de uso. Na prática basta invocar um método para interpretar os códigos no estilo \uxxxx na primeira linha da function.

Comment: Não me referia a isso, e sim a [caracteres combinantes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character). Por exemplo, seu código funciona bem pra string `Ol\u00e1` (que usa um `á` [pré-composto](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precomposed_character)), mesmo representada dessa forma. Creio que seria sim possível tratar de combinantes usando punycode, mas o `reverse` de fato ficaria mais complexo.

Comment: P.S. na prática, a maioria dos sistemas trabalha só com pré-composto mesmo ([mas nem todos](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5943/como-inverter-uma-string-em-javascript/6784?noredirect=1#comment10292_5952)), de modo que as soluções simples em geral são boas o bastante. Apenas "elegi" [a resposta do luiscubal](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/5952/215) pela sua completeza mesmo...

Answer (score 2):

Tantas respostas interessantes, vou deixar [minha contribuição](https://github.com/kvz/phpjs/blob/master/functions/strings/strrev.js) também, criado pelo pessoal do Projeto [PHPJS](http://phpjs.org), um *port* do [strrev()](http://php.net/strrev) do PHP:

```js
function strrev(string) {
  //       discuss at: http://phpjs.org/functions/strrev/
  //      original by: Kevin van Zonneveld (http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net)
  //      bugfixed by: Onno Marsman
  // reimplemented by: Brett Zamir (http://brett-zamir.me)
  //        example 1: strrev('Kevin van Zonneveld');
  //        returns 1: 'dlevennoZ nav niveK'
  //        example 2: strrev('a\u0301haB') === 'Baha\u0301'; // combining
  //        returns 2: true
  //        example 3: strrev('A\uD87E\uDC04Z') === 'Z\uD87E\uDC04A'; // surrogates
  //        returns 3: true

  string = string + '';

  // Performance will be enhanced with the next two lines of code commented
  //      out if you don't care about combining characters
  // Keep Unicode combining characters together with the character preceding
  //      them and which they are modifying (as in PHP 6)
  // See http://unicode.org/reports/tr44/#Property_Table (Me+Mn)
  // We also add the low surrogate range at the beginning here so it will be
  //      maintained with its preceding high surrogate
  var grapheme_extend =
    /(.)([\uDC00-\uDFFF\u0300-\u036F\u0483-\u0489\u0591-\u05BD\u05BF\u05C1\u05C2\u05C4\u05C5\u05C7\u0610-\u061A\u064B-\u065E\u0670\u06D6-\u06DC\u06DE-\u06E4\u06E7\u06E8\u06EA-\u06ED\u0711\u0730-\u074A\u07A6-\u07B0\u07EB-\u07F3\u0901-\u0903\u093C\u093E-\u094D\u0951-\u0954\u0962\u0963\u0981-\u0983\u09BC\u09BE-\u09C4\u09C7\u09C8\u09CB-\u09CD\u09D7\u09E2\u09E3\u0A01-\u0A03\u0A3C\u0A3E-\u0A42\u0A47\u0A48\u0A4B-\u0A4D\u0A51\u0A70\u0A71\u0A75\u0A81-\u0A83\u0ABC\u0ABE-\u0AC5\u0AC7-\u0AC9\u0ACB-\u0ACD\u0AE2\u0AE3\u0B01-\u0B03\u0B3C\u0B3E-\u0B44\u0B47\u0B48\u0B4B-\u0B4D\u0B56\u0B57\u0B62\u0B63\u0B82\u0BBE-\u0BC2\u0BC6-\u0BC8\u0BCA-\u0BCD\u0BD7\u0C01-\u0C03\u0C3E-\u0C44\u0C46-\u0C48\u0C4A-\u0C4D\u0C55\u0C56\u0C62\u0C63\u0C82\u0C83\u0CBC\u0CBE-\u0CC4\u0CC6-\u0CC8\u0CCA-\u0CCD\u0CD5\u0CD6\u0CE2\u0CE3\u0D02\u0D03\u0D3E-\u0D44\u0D46-\u0D48\u0D4A-\u0D4D\u0D57\u0D62\u0D63\u0D82\u0D83\u0DCA\u0DCF-\u0DD4\u0DD6\u0DD8-\u0DDF\u0DF2\u0DF3\u0E31\u0E34-\u0E3A\u0E47-\u0E4E\u0EB1\u0EB4-\u0EB9\u0EBB\u0EBC\u0EC8-\u0ECD\u0F18\u0F19\u0F35\u0F37\u0F39\u0F3E\u0F3F\u0F71-\u0F84\u0F86\u0F87\u0F90-\u0F97\u0F99-\u0FBC\u0FC6\u102B-\u103E\u1056-\u1059\u105E-\u1060\u1062-\u1064\u1067-\u106D\u1071-\u1074\u1082-\u108D\u108F\u135F\u1712-\u1714\u1732-\u1734\u1752\u1753\u1772\u1773\u17B6-\u17D3\u17DD\u180B-\u180D\u18A9\u1920-\u192B\u1930-\u193B\u19B0-\u19C0\u19C8\u19C9\u1A17-\u1A1B\u1B00-\u1B04\u1B34-\u1B44\u1B6B-\u1B73\u1B80-\u1B82\u1BA1-\u1BAA\u1C24-\u1C37\u1DC0-\u1DE6\u1DFE\u1DFF\u20D0-\u20F0\u2DE0-\u2DFF\u302A-\u302F\u3099\u309A\uA66F-\uA672\uA67C\uA67D\uA802\uA806\uA80B\uA823-\uA827\uA880\uA881\uA8B4-\uA8C4\uA926-\uA92D\uA947-\uA953\uAA29-\uAA36\uAA43\uAA4C\uAA4D\uFB1E\uFE00-\uFE0F\uFE20-\uFE26]+)/g;
  // Temporarily reverse
  string = string.replace(grapheme_extend, '$2$1');
  return string.split('')
    .reverse()
    .join('');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## `Array.from`

Se você quiser contornar os problemas com Unicode mencionados pelo @luiscubal, mas de uma maneira mais simples, podemos usar o [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) combinados com métodos `reverse` e `join` para chegar ao resultado desejado.

O código vai ser o seguinte:

```
Array.from(str) // criar um array a partir da string sem problemas com o Unicode
```

Depois, fazemos a mesma lógica apresentada nas outras respostas. Combinamos o `reverse()` e o `join("")`:

```
Array.from(str).reverse().join("")`
```

Vou usar alguns textos de exemplos das outras respostas:

```js
function inverterTexto(str) {
  return Array.from(str).reverse().join("")
}

var t1 = 'Olá  ! Cuidado pois tem também esse caracter  que é um surrogate pair.';
var t2 = '♕ ♖ ♗ ♘';
var t3 = 'サブリミナルメッセージ';
var t4 = '✓ ✔ ✕ ✖ ✗ ✘ ✙ ✚ ✛ ✜ ✝ ✞';
var t5 = 'Olá amigo ✌️! Como vai? ';

console.log(inverterTexto(t1));
console.log(inverterTexto(t2));
console.log(inverterTexto(t3));
console.log(inverterTexto(t4));
console.log(inverterTexto(t5));


var t6 = 'ZA̡͊͠͝LGΌ ISͮ̂҉̯͈͕̹̘̱ TO͇̹̺ͅƝ̴ȳ̳ TH̘Ë͖́̉ ͠P̯͍̭O̚​N̐Y̡ H̸̡̪̯ͨ͊̽̅̾̎Ȩ̬̩̾͛ͪ̈́̀́͘ ̶̧̨̱̹̭̯ͧ̾ͬC̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍M̲̖͊̒ͪͩͬ̚̚͜Ȇ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝S̨̥̫͎̭ͯ̿̔̀ͅ - Demo'

console.log('\n\n', inverterTexto(t6));
```

---

Agradecimentos ao @hkotsubo por esta [excelente resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/443749/112052), que foi a base para elaboração de minha resposta.

---

## Operador Spread (`...`)

Uma alternativa é usar o spread na string, ao invés do `split`, para transformar em um array e aplicar o método `reverse()` e `join()` para alcançar o mesmo objetivo.

De exemplo, vou reaproveitar o código acima, fazendo apenas o ajuste para usarmos o spread. Teremos a nova versão da função `inverterTexto`:

```
function inverterTexto(str) {
  //        ⬇️   temos esse ajuste com o operador spread
  return [...str].reverse().join("")
}
```

Temos os mesmos exemplos anterioes mas agora usando a função acima:

```js
function inverterTexto(str) {
  //        ⬇️   temos esse ajuste com o operador spread
  return [...str].reverse().join("")
}

var t1 = 'Olá  ! Cuidado pois tem também esse caracter  que é um surrogate pair.';
var t2 = '♕ ♖ ♗ ♘';
var t3 = 'サブリミナルメッセージ';
var t4 = '✓ ✔ ✕ ✖ ✗ ✘ ✙ ✚ ✛ ✜ ✝ ✞';
var t5 = 'Olá amigo ✌️! Como vai? ';

console.log(inverterTexto(t1));
console.log(inverterTexto(t2));
console.log(inverterTexto(t3));
console.log(inverterTexto(t4));
console.log(inverterTexto(t5));


var t6 = 'ZA̡͊͠͝LGΌ ISͮ̂҉̯͈͕̹̘̱ TO͇̹̺ͅƝ̴ȳ̳ TH̘Ë͖́̉ ͠P̯͍̭O̚​N̐Y̡ H̸̡̪̯ͨ͊̽̅̾̎Ȩ̬̩̾͛ͪ̈́̀́͘ ̶̧̨̱̹̭̯ͧ̾ͬC̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍M̲̖͊̒ͪͩͬ̚̚͜Ȇ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝S̨̥̫͎̭ͯ̿̔̀ͅ - Demo'

console.log('\n\n', inverterTexto(t6));
```

## `String.prototype[@@iterator]()` vs `String.prototype.split()`

### `split('')`

Nos exemplos das outras respostas, usar o `split("")` ocasionava problemas quando as strings possuiam caracteres Unicode. O porque disso se deve ao fato mencionado a seguir:

> Atenção: Se uma string vazia (`""`) for usada como separador, a string **não será dividida entre cada caractere percebido pelo usuário ou entre cada caractere unicode** (codepoint), mas entre cada **codeunit** UTF-16. Isso destrói [pares substitutos](https://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#utf16-2) (*surrogate pairs*)...

<sup>traduzida desta [fonte](https://cgi.cse.unsw.edu.au/%7Ecs2041/doc/MDN_javascript_reference/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split.html#Syntax)</sup>

Por essa explicação, o código abaixo não funciona como esperado. `split` é usado para dividir uma string em substrings, com base em algum separador.

```js
var t5 = 'Olá amigo ✌️! Como vai? ';

console.log(t5.split('').reverse().join('')); // �� ?iav omoC !��️✌ ogima álO
```

### `@@iterator`

[Nesta documentação](https://O%20m%C3%A9todo%20@@iterator%20de%20uma%20string%20implementa%20o%20protocolo%20iter%C3%A1vel%20e%20permite%20que%20as%20strings%20sejam%20consumidas%20pela%20maioria%20das%20sintaxes%20que%20esperam%20iter%C3%A1veis,%20como%20a%20sintaxe%20spread%20e%20loops%20for...of.%20Ele%20retorna%20um%20iterador%20que%20produz%20os%20pontos%20de%20c%C3%B3digo%20Unicode%20do%20valor%20da%20string%20como%20strings%20individuais.) temos a definiçào (traduzida):

> O método `@@iterator` de uma string implementa o protocolo iterável e permite que as strings sejam consumidas pela maioria das sintaxes que esperam iteráveis, como a sintaxe `spread` e loops `for...of`. Ele retorna um **iterador** que produz os **codepoints Unicode do valor da string como strings individuais**.

Isso quer dizer que podemos criar uma solução em que iteramos sobre a string com um loop `for...of` e combinamos o método de array `unshift` para montar uma string invertida. Como ficaria a função `inverterTexto`:

```
function inverterTexto(str) {     
  const tmp = [];
  
  //  ⬇️ temos esse ajuste com o iterador, usando o loop for...of
  for (const char of str) {
    tmp.unshift(char); // o array tmp vai ter a string invertida
  } 
  
  return tmp.join("")
}
```

Veja um exemplo usando a função acima:

```js
function inverterTexto(str) {
  const tmp = [];

  //  ⬇️ temos esse ajuste com o iterador, usando o loop for...of
  for (const char of str) {
    tmp.unshift(char); // o array tmp vai ter a string invertida
  }

  return tmp.join("")
}

var t5 = 'Olá amigo ✌️! Como vai? ';

console.log(inverterTexto(t5));
```

## ***[Surrogate pairs](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-encoding#surrogate-pairs)*** e ***[Grapheme Cluster](https://unicode.org/reports/tr29/#Grapheme_Cluster_Boundaries)***

### TL;DR

Strings são iteradas por codepoint Unicode. Isso significa que os Grapheme Cluster serão divididos, mas os Surrogate pairs serão preservados. Por exemplo, veja o emoji  na string "" no código abaixo:

```js
console.log([...""]);
```

Como resultado, será divido e retornado o array `['', '']`. "" divide-se no emoji básico *mão apontando para a direita* ('') e  o emoji *tom de pele escuro* (''). Isso ocorre por causa do caractere de [junção de zero largura](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_joiner) (`<ZWJ>`, `U+200D`), para representar caracteres que são compostos por vários glifos.

Comment: E pode usar spread também `[...str].reverse().join('')`, exemplo prático: `console.log([...'✌️! Como vai?  ✓ ✔ ✕ ✖ ✗ ✘ ✙ ✚ ✛ ✜ ✝ ✞'].reverse().join(''));`. Recomendo que coloque a explicação da diferença do `String.prototype.split` para o `@@iterator()`, para que fique claro o porque se comportam de forma diferente, também seria interessante explicar sobre o `<ZWJ>` (U+200D). Aqui seque uma introdução que poderá usar de base para adicionar a sua resposta: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/@@iterator

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento boa sugestão! Vou dá uma estudada e atualizo a resposta assim que possível.