# Por que, em JavaScript, às vezes uma string com emoji é “quebrada” e, em outras situações, não?

Tags: javascript, string, caracteres

Considerando o trecho de código a seguir:

```js
const str = 'Olá! ';

str.split('').forEach((char) => console.log(char));
```

Utilizando o método `split`, note que (quase) todos os caracteres foram separados da string corretamente. Contudo, o emoji foi quebrado em duas partes — `�` e `�`.

Mas, se eu usar algum recurso mais novo da linguagem (como a [implementação de strings para o protocolo de iteração](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/@@iterator)), o emoji não é dividido em duas partes. Veja estes dois exemplos:

```js
const str = 'Olá! ';

for (const char of str) {
  console.log(char);
}
```

Ou até mesmo um exemplo mais similar ao primeiro excerto de código desta pergunta. A única diferença é que, ao contrário do `split`, a sintaxe de espalhamento foi utilizada:

```js
const str = 'Olá! ';

[...str].forEach((char) => console.log(char));
```

A sintaxe de espalhamento utiliza, por baixo dos panos, o protocolo de iteradores do ECMAScript.

Por que acontece isso? O que provoca essa diferença?

Comment: O problema é i `split()` que provavelmente não foi preparado pra isso, não parece ter alguma coisa a ver com iterador ou algo assim.

Comment: Fagmento da documentação do [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) para o separador vazio: `Se o separador for uma string vazia, str será convertido em um array de caracteres.` Os emojis são formados pares de sustituição `console.log('BC'.charCodeAt(0));console.log('BC'.charCodeAt(1));` e o `split()` entende como 2 caracteres. Documentação sobre [pares de substituição](https://unicodebook.readthedocs.io/unicode_encodings.html#surrogates)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Provavelmente você já sabe o que é um Unicode code point (se não sabe, [leia aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/394834/112052)). Mas de forma resumida, todo caractere (inclusive *emojis*) possui um valor numérico associado, que é chamado de code point.

No caso do emoji , o code point dele é [U+1F600 ("GRINNING FACE")](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1F600/index.htm).

O que acontece é que internamente o JavaScript representa code points acima de U+FFFF na forma de [*surrogate pairs*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#Code_points_from_U+010000_to_U+10FFFF) <- neste link tem a descrição do algoritmo, mas basicamente o code point U+1F600 é "quebrado"/decomposto em dois valores: 0xD83D e 0xDE00 ([provavelmente porque internamente as strings são armazenadas em UTF-16](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-encoding)).

```js
const str = '';

console.log(str.codePointAt(0).toString(16)); // 1f600

console.log(str.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)); // d83d
console.log(str.charCodeAt(1).toString(16)); // de00
```

---

Na documentação de [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) há um aviso:

> *When the empty string ("") is used as a separator, the string is **not** split by user-perceived characters (grapheme clusters) or unicode characters (codepoints), but by UTF-16 codeunits. This destroys surrogate pairs.*

Ou seja, ao fazer o `split`, você estará iterando individualmente pelas partes do *surrogate pair*. Isso também influencia em outros aspectos da string, como por exemplo o tamanho dela e a iteração pelos caracteres usando um `for` tradicional:

```js
const str = '';

console.log(str.length); // 2
for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++)
    console.log(str[i]);
```

O tamanho é 2 porque [`length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length) também leva em conta os *code units* (na documentação diz: "*the length of the string, in UTF-16 code units*"), e um *surrogate pair* usa 2 *code units*.

E ao fazer um *loop* pelos caracteres da string, ele imprime os dois code points do *surrogate pair*.

---

Já o operador `of` e a sintaxe de espalhamento operam sobre os code points da string, por isso o *emoji* é tratado corretamente nestes casos, pois na [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/@@iterator) é dito que o iterador de uma `String` itera pelos code points da mesma (e [a sintaxe de espalhamento usa o protocolo de iteradores](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols#Examples_using_the_iteration_protocols) por baixo dos panos, por isso funciona corretamente).

Outra forma de obter um array de code points é usando [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from):

```js
const str = 'Olá! ';

console.log(Array.from(str)); // [ "O", "l", "á", "!", " ", "" ]
```

---

Para saber mais, sugiro o artigo: [JavaScript has a Unicode problem](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-unicode).

**Lembrando que esse problema não ocorre somente com *emojis*, e sim com qualquer caractere cujo code point seja maior que U+FFFF.**

Outro detalhe é que nem todo caractere (no sentido de "um 'desenho único' que vemos na tela") é composto por apenas um code point. [Existem casos mais bizarros que só o Unicode traz para você](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/439066/112052).

Comment: +1 Muito boa resposta. Apenas uma duvida. `Array.from(str)` meio que contorna esse problema de fato ou não? A única atencao que tive foi que ficou a string vazia no array, mas isso é o de menos.

Comment: @CmteCardeal Que string vazia? No último exemplo, antes do emoji tem um espaço, o que está correto pq ele faz parte da string. É isso?

Comment: Foi mal, escrevi errado. Mas é isso mesmo.

Comment: @CmteCardeal Blz. Então voltando à dúvida, a resposta é sim. `Array.from` resolve o problema do `split` e retorna um array da forma esperada.