# Como comparar cada caractere de uma String em Java?

Tags: java, string, comparação, char

Estou criando uma aplicação em Java onde eu percorro uma `String` com um laço `for` e preciso verificar cada caractere dessa `String`. Exemplo:

```
for (int i = 0; i < texto.length(); i++) {
    char caractere = texto.charAt(i);

    if (char.equals("?")){
        System.out.println("Você não pode adicionar ao texto interrogação.");

    } else if (char.equals(" ")) {
        System.out.println("Você não pode adicionar ao texto espaços.");
    }
    // ...
}
```

Neste exemplo acima, eu sei que o método `equals` não existe em `char` e isso foi apenas para ilustrar o que eu gostaria de fazer.

Como posso comparar cada caractere da `String` em Java? É possível?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Como o método `chartAt` retorna um `char` que é um tipo primitivo, você consegue fazer uma comparação de igualdade com `==`, porém precisa colocar o caractere em entre aspas simples, para identificar que trata-se de um `char`:

```
caractere == '?'
```

---

Ficaria mais ou menos da seguinte forma:

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String texto = "Teste ? ";

    for (int i = 0; i < texto.length(); i++) {
        char caractere = texto.charAt(i);

        if (caractere == '?'){
            System.out.println("Você não pode adicionar ao texto interrogação.");

        } else if (caractere == ' ') {
            System.out.println("Você não pode adicionar ao texto espaços.");
        }
    }
  }
}
```

> Veja online: https://repl.it/repls/LegitimateExcellentAddition

Answer (score 6):

Só para constar, para verificar se uma `String` contém algum caractere, não precisa percorrer todos os caracteres em um *loop*. Basta usar o [método `contains`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence)):

```
if (texto.contains("?")) {
    System.out.println("Você não pode adicionar ao texto interrogação.");
} else if (texto.contains(" ")) {
    System.out.println("Você não pode adicionar ao texto espaços.");
}
```

Só que agora tive que usar aspas duplas, porque o método recebe uma `String` e não um `char`.

A diferença, claro, é que no seu *loop*, como você percorre todos os caracteres, então se a `String` tiver um espaço e um `?`, ambas as mensagens serão exibidas (e se tiver mais de uma ocorrência, então a respectiva mensagem será exibida várias vezes). Já no código acima somente uma delas é exibida - a menos que você tire o `else`, aí ambas serão exibidas:

```
if (texto.contains("?")) {
    System.out.println("Você não pode adicionar ao texto interrogação.");
} 
if (texto.contains(" ")) {
    System.out.println("Você não pode adicionar ao texto espaços.");
}
```

Outra diferença é que `contains` não se limita a verificar apenas um caractere:

```
System.out.println("abcdef".contains("cde")); // true
```

---

Indo um pouco além, a comparação `char` a `char` funciona bem para textos em português (e em vários outros idiomas), mas tem suas limitações, já que hoje em dia é possível termos códigos assim:

```
String texto = "a";
for (int i = 0; i < texto.length(); i++) {
    char c = texto.charAt(i);
    System.out.printf("%c - %06X\n", c, (int) c);
}
```

Sim, um emoji direto no código. Se a sua IDE não suportar isso, você pode construir a mesma `String` assim:

```
int[] codepoints = { 0x61, 0x1f4a9 };
String texto = new String(codepoints, 0, codepoints.length);
```

Apesar da `String` ter dois "caracteres" (a letra `a` e o emoji ), a saída mostra 3 `char`'s:

```
a - 000061
? - 00D83D
? - 00DCA9
```

Isso porque [um `char` em Java possui 16 bits](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html), e só é capaz de guardar valores até 65535. Mas o Unicode define uma quantidade muito maior de caracteres, então caracteres como o emoji [PILE OF POO](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f4a9/index.htm), cujo code point é U+1F4A9 (ou seja, um valor maior do que um `char` suporta) são "quebrados" em dois - no caso, 0xD83D e 0xDCA9, que é chamado de "*surrogate pair*" (isso porque [internamente o Java guarda as `String`'s em UTF-16](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9699071) - para entender melhor, leia [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/394834/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/443744/112052)).

Ou seja, se eu quiser buscar pelo emoji, não adianta percorrer os `char`'s um a um. Uma solução não muito boa seria verificar o próximo caractere para saber se é um *surrogate pair*:

```
for (int i = 0; i < texto.length(); i++) {
    char c = texto.charAt(i);
    // verifica o surrogate pair (precisa verificar o próximo caractere)
    if (c == 0xd83d && i < texto.length() - 1 && texto.charAt(i + 1) == 0xdca9) {
        System.out.println("tem emoji");
    }
}
```

O `if` acima também pode ser assim:

```
// não preciso saber o valor do próximo, só preciso verificar se são um surrogate pair
if (c == 0xd83d && i < texto.length() - 1 && Character.isSurrogatePair(c, texto.charAt(i + 1))) {
```

Mas neste caso, acho melhor usar `contains`:

```
if (texto.contains("")) {
    System.out.println("tem emoji");
}
```

Ou então percorrer os code points da `String`:

```
int codePointCount = texto.codePointCount(0, texto.length());
for (int i = 0; i < codePointCount; i++) {
    int cp = texto.codePointAt(i);
    if (cp == 0x1f4a9) {
        System.out.println("tem emoji");
    }

    // comparação com char literal continua funcionando para valores abaixo de 0xffff
    if (cp == 'a') {
        System.out.println("Tem letra 'a'");
    }
}
```