# Separa letras por linha javascript

Tags: javascript, string

Sou novo na programação e gostaria que alguém me ajudasse, por favor. Eu preciso separar as letras de uma palavra por linha

```js
var n=require("readline-sync")

var b1
var b2

b2=n.question("Digite uma palavra")

b1=b2.split("")
console.log(b1)
```

Basicamente meu código está assim, mas eu perciso que cada letra da palavra fique em uma linha diferente, alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 6):

Vale lembrar que a sua string possuir caracteres cujo *code-point* seja superior a U+FFFF, o comportamento pode não ser o esperado, veja:

```js
const string = 'Olá! ';

string
  .split('')
  .forEach((char) => console.log(char));
```

Saiba mais sobre o porquê disso [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/443749/69296).

Então, se você quiser dividir strings que possam conter esses tipos de caracteres corretamente, você pode utilizar recursos mais modernos da linguagem, como o [operador de espalhamento](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) (`...`):

```js
const string = 'Olá! ';

[...string].forEach((char) => console.log(char));
```

Ou você pode utilizar um laço [`for..of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of), que utiliza o [protocolo de iteração](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols) *built-in* de strings, assim como a notação de espalhamento acima, de uma forma mais explícita:

```js
const string = 'Olá! ';

for (const char of string) {
  console.log(char);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Basta adicionar à string o caractere especial `\n` em cada caractere. Utilize o método `split` para separar e depois utilizar o método `join` para juntar tudo com este caractere.

Dessa forma, cada letra da string será imprimida em diferentes linhas.

```js
let palavra = "PROGRAMAÇÃO";
palavra = palavra.split("").join("\n");

console.log(palavra);
```

Uma outra forma até mais simples se você precisar manter os caracteres separados, é utilizar o método `forEach` passando uma função que recebe um elemento da lista e imprime.

```js
let palavra = "PROGRAMAÇÃO";
palavra = palavra.split("");

palavra.forEach((caractere) => {
    console.log(caractere);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer um `forEach` no seu array, ficaria dessa forma:

```
b1.forEach(letter => console.log(letter))
```

Comment: Não é necessário utilizar o `\n` neste caso porque o `console.log` já faz quebra de linha no final.

Comment: Realmente não é necessario, obrigado pela dica