# Problema ao contar quantas vezes um caractere se repete em dada string

Tags: javascript

Estou com um problema ao resolver um exercício para determinar quantas vezes um caractere se repete numa string:

> Neste desafio, você deve implementar a função `vezesLetraAparece`, que:
>
> - Recebe 2 parâmetros: `frase`, que deve ser uma string e `letra`, outra string;
> - Retorne o número de vezes que letra aparece na frase.
>
> Complete a função `vezesLetraAparece` abaixo.
>
> - É esperado que a função retorne um número inteiro.
> - A função aceita os seguintes parâmetros:
>
>   1. `frase` (string)
>   2. `letra` (string)

O código que fiz está assim, mas não está funcionando.

```
function vezesLetraAparece(frase, letra) {
  var resultado = [ ];
  for (var letra = 0; letra < frase.length; letra++); {
    resultado.push (frase[letra])
  }
}
```

Por quê? Como posso o corrigir?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O primeiro problema é que você não está retornando nada da função `vezesLetraAparece`. Note que há ausência de uma declaração `return` no corpo da função e, por causa disso, ela *sempre* retornará `undefined`.

Portanto, colocando um `return` para retornar o valor de `resultado` após o laço `for` terminar, teremos algo assim:

```js
function vezesLetraAparece(frase, letra) {
  var resultado = [];

  for (var letra = 0; letra < frase.length; letra++) {
    resultado.push (frase[letra]);
  }
  
  return resultado;
}

console.log(vezesLetraAparece('abcaba', 'a'));
```

Mas, ao executar o código, percebemos que há um outro erro. O código não está retornando, de fato, o número de vezes que a letra passada no 2º argumento ocorre na string. O `for` simplesmente está fazendo a divisão da string em um array, sendo cada elemento um caractere.

Portanto, percebe-se que utilizar um array como resultado (ou acumulador), nesse caso, não faz muito sentido. Você também há de verificar se a letra correspondente à iteração atual corresponde (*é igual*) àquela que nos interessa. Você não está fazendo essa verificação também.

Enfim, precisamos utilizar um número (o qual iniciaremos como `0`) como contador e uma declaração [`if`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else) para contar somente as letras que são iguais àquela que buscamos.

Teremos, então:

```js
function vezesLetraAparece(frase, letra) {
  var resultado = 0;

  for (var indiceLetra = 0; indiceLetra < frase.length; indiceLetra++) {
    if (frase[indiceLetra] === letra) {
      resultado++; // Somamos 1 ao contador.
    }
  }
  
  return resultado;
}

console.log(vezesLetraAparece('abcaba', 'a')); // 3
```

Note também que tive que mudar o nome da variável `letra` (no `for`) para `indiceLetra`. Se o nome continuasse como `letra`, estaríamos sobre-escrevendo o parâmetro `letra`, declarado na função. Isso se chama [*variable shadowing*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) e, nesse caso, é indesejável.

Também tinha um ponto e vírgula a mais depois no `for`. Como ele [impede o o bloco do `for` de ser executado](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18464187/7445826), hemos de o remover.

---

Para simplificar o `for` um pouco (e, de quebra, lidar com um eventual problema ligado à ["decomposição" de certos caracteres Unicode](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/443744/69296)), você pode utilizar um laço [`for..of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of):

```js
function vezesLetraAparece(frase, letra) {
  var resultado = 0;

  for (const letraAtual of frase) {
    if (letraAtual === letra) {
      resultado++;
    }
  }
  
  return resultado;
}

console.log(vezesLetraAparece('abcaba', 'a')); // 3
```

<sup>Óbvio que existem diversas outras formas de se resolver esse problema. Essas são apenas duas das incontáveis possibilidades. À medida que você for aprendendo mais sobre JavaScript, será capaz de pensar em outras formas de resolvê-lo. São, não obstante e provavelmente, as mais simples. :)</sup>

Comment: Obrigado amigo pela explicação! Estou começando no JavaScript agora, algumas coisas ainda esta difícil de pegar, mas um dia chego lá e fico fera que nem você.