# Como contar ocorrências de uma letra em uma frase?

Tags: javascript, string

Estou tentando fazer um exercicio cujo o objetivo é saber quantas vezes uma determinada letra aparece na frase, estava tentando fazer assim:

```
var frase = "o homem é o lobo do homem";
var letra = "o";

for (var i = 0; i < frase.length; i++) {
  if (letra == frase) {}
}
```

Sou iniciante em JavaScript, minha duvida é como relacionar o `for` com o `if` para caso tenha a letra ele contar.

Answer (score 8):

Faça uma outra variável para servir como "variável contadora". No caso do exemplo abaixo, chamei de `quantidade`, que a cada `frase[i]` se for igual a `letra` irá adicionar +1, até chegar no resultado final.

Por que `[i]` entre colchetes?

Cada letra em uma string tem um índice e começando da primeira letra esse índice é `0`.

No exemplo, a string `"o homem é o lobo do homem"`, o primeiro `o` tem o índice `0`, o índice `1` é um  , o índice `2` é o `h` e assim sucessivamente.

Ou seja `frase[0]` seria = `o`.

```js
var frase = "o homem é o lobo do homem";
var letra = "o";
var quantidade = 0

for (var i = 0; i < frase.length; i++) {
  if (frase[i] == letra) {
    quantidade++
  }
}

document.write(quantidade)
```

Answer (score 6):

Só para complementar as outras respostas, existem algumas situações que você deve tomar cuidado, já que há surpresas que só o [Unicode](https://home.unicode.org/) traz pra você :-)

Faça o teste abaixo:

```js
function comFilter(frase, letraProcurada) {
    return [...frase].filter(letra => letra === letraProcurada).length;
}

function comForEach(frase, letraProcurada) {
    var total = 0;
    [...frase].forEach(letra => {
        if (letra === letraProcurada)
            total++;
    });
    return total;
}

function comSplit(frase, letraProcurada) {
    return frase.split(letraProcurada).length - 1;
}

function comRegex(frase, letraProcurada) {
    var re = new RegExp(letraProcurada, "g");
    return [...frase.matchAll(re)].length;
}

function comFor(frase, letraProcurada) {
    var quantidade = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < frase.length; i++) {
        if (frase[i] == letraProcurada) {
            quantidade++
        }
    }
    return quantidade;
}

function testar(frase, letraProcurada) {
    console.log(`procurando "${letraProcurada}" em "${frase}"`);
    for (const func of [comFilter, comForEach, comSplit, comRegex, comFor]) {
        console.log(`- ${func.name} = ${func(frase, letraProcurada)}`);
    }
}

testar('até é noé', 'é');
testar('até é noé', 'é');
```

Basicamente eu peguei as soluções das outras respostas e testei 2 vezes cada - **aparentemente** com a mesma string, mas veja que os resultados são diferentes (no segundo teste, todas as contagens deram zero).

Isso acontece porque a segunda string está na forma NFD. Se quiser saber mais detalhes sobre o que é isso, [leia aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/406545/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/394834/112052), mas basicamente, letras acentuadas como o "é" podem ser representadas de duas maneiras: como o próprio caractere "é" ou como dois caracteres: o "e" (sem acento) e o "´" (o acento) - a primeira forma é chamada NFC, e a segunda, NFD (leia os links já indicados para entender melhor).

Só que visualmente você não consegue perceber a diferença, porque ambos são renderizados da mesma forma. E aí dá problema na hora de contabilizar as contagens, porque nos *loops*, na regex e no `split`, a segunda string - que está em NFD - considera que o "e" e o acento são caracteres separados, e por isso nenhum deles é igual ao `é`, resultando em zero.

Para que funcione nesses casos, uma alternativa é normalizar as strings para NFC:

```
function ocorrencias(frase, letraProcurada) {
    var qtd = 0;
    letraProcurada = letraProcurada.normalize('NFC');
    for (var letra of frase.normalize('NFC')) {
        if (letra === letraProcurada)
            qtd++;
    }
    return qtd;
}
```

E eu também uso o [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of), que já itera pelos caracteres da string corretamente.

Desta forma, funciona até mesmo com letras de outros alfabetos, e também com *emojis*:

```js
function comFilter(frase, letraProcurada) {
    return [...frase].filter(letra => letra === letraProcurada).length;
}

function comForEach(frase, letraProcurada) {
    var total = 0;
    [...frase].forEach(letra => {
        if (letra === letraProcurada)
            total++;
    });
    return total;
}

function comSplit(frase, letraProcurada) {
    return frase.split(letraProcurada).length - 1;
}

function comRegex(frase, letraProcurada) {
    var re = new RegExp(letraProcurada, "g");
    return [...frase.matchAll(re)].length;
}

function comFor(frase, letraProcurada) {
    var quantidade = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < frase.length; i++) {
        if (frase[i] == letraProcurada) {
            quantidade++
        }
    }
    return quantidade;
}

function ocorrencias(frase, letraProcurada) {
    var qtd = 0;
    letraProcurada = letraProcurada.normalize('NFC');
    for (var letra of frase.normalize('NFC')) {
        if (letra === letraProcurada)
            qtd++;
    }
    return qtd;
}

function testar(frase, letraProcurada) {
    console.log(`procurando "${letraProcurada}" em "${frase}"`);
    for (const func of [comFilter, comForEach, comSplit, comRegex, comFor, ocorrencias]) {
        console.log(`- ${func.name} = ${func(frase, letraProcurada)}`);
    }
}

testar('até é noé', 'é'); // NFC
testar('até é noé', 'é'); // NFD
testar('abc  def  xyz', '');
testar('abc  def  xyz', '');
```

Obs: com emojis não vai funcionar se eles forem uma [*emoji ZWJ sequence*](https://blog.emojipedia.org/emoji-zwj-sequences-three-letters-many-possibilities/), mas aí já estamos fugindo demais do escopo da pergunta...

Comment: @AugustoVasques Se sobrar um tempo eu faço depois (mas tenho um palpite: *acho* que a minha solução será mais lenta, já que precisa normalizar a string antes).

Comment: Dava pra linkar esta outra pergunta também: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/443744/69296 :D

Comment: @AugustoVasques Tá lá: https://jsbench.me/9xkit4zsbp/1 (o for simples foi mais rápido, regex foi o pior - normaliize foi a segunda pior)

Comment: Esse link é valioso. Obrigado.

Answer (score 5):

Uma solução alternativa é transformar a *string* num *array* para poder usar [métodos próprios do *array*](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) como `filter`, `reduce` ou `forEach`.

Basicamente pode fazer isso usando dessa forma: `[...frase]`.
O operador *Spread* (`...`) pega um objeto como uma string e os colchetes (`[]`) transforma num *array* ([leia mais aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)).

Com isso podemos usar o método `filter`, que vai iterar para cada "elemento" do *array*, ou seja, cada letra, mas com uma sintaxe mais simples que fazer um `for` ou `foreach`, então podemos "filtrar" só a letra que queremos, e contar quantas foram encontradas usando `length`:

```js
var frase = "o homem é o lobo do homem"
var letraProcurada = "o";
var total = [...frase].filter(letra => letra === letraProcurada).length;

console.log("total=" + total);
```

Na prática o `filter` faz algo como `[...frase].forEach(....`.
Para ilustrar, outro exemplo usando `forEach`:

```js
var frase = "o homem é o lobo do homem"
var total = 0;
var letraProcurada = "o";

[...frase].forEach(letra => { 
   if (letra === letraProcurada) total ++; 
});

console.log(total);
```

Answer (score 3):

É possível utilizar o método nativo [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) para contar a ocorrência de uma string em outra.

O método `split([separator[, limit]])` divide uma [`String`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) em um [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) de `Strings` cujo o separador é o parâmetro `separator` que pode ser uma `String` ou uma [expressão regular](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).
Quando encontrado, o separador é removido da string e as sub strings são retornadas em um array.
Se o separador não ocorrer ou for omitido, o array irá conter um elemento consistindo da string inteira.
O que implica que o [comprimento do array](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length) retornado por `split()` será sempre o número de ocorrências do separador mais um:

```js
let frase = prompt("Digite uma frase.").normalize("NFC");
let letra = prompt("Digite letra ou texto para contar as ocorrências.").normalize("NFC");

   
console.log(frase.split(letra).length - 1);
```

Outra possibilidade é [criar uma expressão expressão regular](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/RegExp) com um padrão com de correspondência como separador e obter um [iterador](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iteratores_e_geradores) contendo todas as correspondência com o método [`String.prototype.matchAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll), então [espalhá-lo](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) em um array e apenas obter o tamanho desse array:

```js
let frase = prompt("Digite uma frase.").normalize("NFC");
let letra = prompt("Digite letra ou texto para contar as ocorrências.").normalize("NFC");


re = new RegExp(letra, "g");

console.log([...frase.matchAll(re)].length);
```

## EDIT:

Em ambos os fragmentos foram adicionados códigos que colocam a strings de entrada no [*Formato de Normalização Canônico de Composição*](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize). Segundo [orientação do usuário HKotsubo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/486938/137387) que alerta que a equivalência visual de strings UNICODE pode abrigar uma discrepância nos [codepoints](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ponto_de_c%C3%B3digo) de seus caracteres o que levaria qualquer comparação não tratada a uma contagem equivocada de ocorrências.
Para corrigir essa possível discrepância foi usado o método [`String.prototype.normalize()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize).

Answer (score 1):

Uma opção interessante utilizando regex.

```js
let frase = 'o homem é o lobo do homem';

let o_qtd = frase.match(/o/ig).length

console.log(o_qtd);
```

o_qtd será 7.

No regex 'o' é a ororrência, i = case insensitive e g = global, para encontrar todas as ocorrências.